# Split 10GB text file 1) with a minimum size of the output files of 40MB and 2) after a specific string (</record>)

Tags: split

I got a big text file (10GB, .xml, contains over 1 million tags like this:  `<record>`text`</record>`) which I splitted into parts to use it. But to be able to automate my working process, it is necessary that every part ends with a specific tag: `</record>`. And it is also necessary that every part has got at least the size of about 40MB.

Comment: Do you have an idea of the average line length? and does it vary a lot (looking at it from a large scale)?

Comment: I found line lengths starting from 9 characters, the maximum is about 120 characters. All the records in this .xml file are similar to this example:

Comment: `<record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" type="Authority">
    <leader>02379nz  a2200517o  4500</leader>
    <controlfield tag="001">100169600</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="003">DE-101</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="005">20080405154152.0</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="008">900615n||aznnnabbn           | aaa    |c</controlfield>
    <datafield tag="024" ind1="7" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">http://d-nb.info/gnd/100169600</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">uri</subfield>
    </datafield>
  </record>`

Comment: One more question: *is* the last line of a "division" (when cut into pieces) "</record>" or does the last line of a section *contain* "</record>". The first one would make it much easier, otherwise a line would have to be separated and divided into two sections. That is a handicap when dealing with huge files.

Comment: `</record>` _is_ the last line of every division (no characters before and after it). You have got a solution?

Comment: Working on it, have to see if it will be fast enough on huge files.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! It doesn't have to be very fast for me!

Comment: It seems to work properly, but please test it in a ~50mb file (into 5mb slices e.g.) to check if all is like you need it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script below slices a (large) file into slices. I didn't use the `split` command, since the content of your file has to be "rounded" by records. The size of the slices you can set in the head section of the script.

#### The procedure

*Difficulties*
Because the script should be able to deal with huge files, either python's `read()` or `readlines()` cannot be used; the script would attempt to load the whole file at once into memory, which would certainly choke your system. At the same time, divisions have to be made, "rounding" sections by a whole record. The script should therefore somehow be able to identify or "read" the file's content.

What seems to be the only option is to use:

```
with open(file) as src:
    for line in src:
```

which reads the file line by line.

*Approach*
In the script I chose a two-step approach:

1. Analyze the file (size, number of slices, number of lines, number of records, records per section), then creating a list of sections or "markers" (by line index).
2. reading the file again, but now allocating the lines to separate files.

The procedure to append the lines to the separate slices (files) one by one seems inefficient, but from all I tried it turned out to be the most efficient, fastest and least consuming option.

*How I tested*
I created an `xml` file of a little over 10GB, filled with records like your example. I set the size of slices to `45mb`. On my not-so-recent system (Pentium Dual-Core CPU E6700 @ 3.20GHz × 2), the script's analysis produced the following:

```
analyzing file...

checking file size...
file size: 10767 mb
calculating number of slices...
239 slices of 45 mb
checking number of lines...
number of lines: 246236399
checking number of records...
number of records: 22386000
calculating number records per section ...
records per section: 93665
```

Then it started creating slices of 45 mb, taking appr. 25-27 seconds per slice to create.

```
creating slice 1
creating slice 2
creating slice 3
creating slice 4
creating slice 5
```

and so on...

The processor was occupied for 45-50 % during the process, using ~850-880mb of my memory (of 4GB). The computer was reasonably usable during the process.

The whole procedure took one hour and a half. On a more recent system, it should take substantially less time.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import time

#---
file = "/path/to/big/file.xml" 
out_dir = "/path/to/save/slices"
size_ofslices = 45 # in mb
identifying_string = "</record>"
#---

line_number = -1
records = [0]

# analyzing file -------------------------------------------

print("analyzing file...\n")
# size in mb
print("checking file size...")
size = int(os.stat(file).st_size/1000000)
print("file size:", size, "mb")
# number of sections
print("calculating number of slices...")
sections = int(size/size_ofslices)
print(sections, "slices of", size_ofslices, "mb")
# misc. data
print("checking number of lines...")
with open(file) as src:
    for line in src:
        line_number = line_number+1
        if identifying_string in line:
            records.append(line_number)
# last index (number of lines -1)
ns_oflines = line_number
print("number of lines:", ns_oflines)
# number of records
print("checking number of records...")
ns_records = len(records)-1
print("number of records:", ns_records)
# records per section
print("calculating number records per section ...")
ns_recpersection = int(ns_records/sections)
print("records per section:", ns_recpersection)

# preparing data -------------------------------------------

rec_markers = [i for i in range(ns_records) if i% ns_recpersection == 0]+[ns_records]   # dividing records (indexes of) in slices
line_markers = [records[i] for i in rec_markers]                                        # dividing lines (indexes of) in slices
line_markers[-1] = ns_oflines; line_markers.pop(-2)                                     # setting lias linesection until last line

# creating sections ----------------------------------------

sl = 1
line_number = 0

curr_marker = line_markers[sl]
outfile = out_dir+"/"+"slice_"+str(sl)+".txt"

def writeline(outfile, line):
    with open(outfile, "a") as out:
        out.write(line)

with open(file) as src:
    print("creating slice", sl)
    for line in src:
        if line_number <= curr_marker:
            writeline(outfile, line)
        else:
            sl = sl+1
            curr_marker = line_markers[sl]
            outfile = out_dir+"/"+"slice_"+str(sl)+".txt"
            print("creating slice", sl)
            writeline(outfile, line)       
        line_number = line_number+1
```

#### How to use

Copy the script into an empty file, set the path to your "big file", the path to the directory to save the slices and the size of the slices. Save it as `slice.py` and run it by the command:

```
/path/to/slice.py
```

#### Notes

- The big file's size should exceed the slice's size at least a few times. How bigger the difference the more reliable the size of the (output) slices will be.
- The assumption was made that the average size of records (seen in the bigger picture) is about the same. Looking at the huge amount of data here one would expect that would be an acceptable assumption, but you'll have to check (by looking if there is a big difference in the size of the slices).

Comment: Wow. I studied your answer excitedly. Until tomorrow my system is fully occupied, then I will try and report of course. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The result is perfect! Having a slightly worse system the script took 101 minutes to execute. Thank you very, very much!!

Comment: @mischa004 Glad it works! It was fun working on it.